# баг? в коде. выдает ошибку name 'pat' is not defined

Tags: python

**не хочу, чтобы вы код разбирали, показываю переменную и где она используется.**

```
rdata = json.loads(r.text)
pat = rdata['data']['pat']
get_track_by_tags(tags, pat, duration, autoplay=True, loop=loop)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(https://colab.research.google.com/github/ferluht/Mubert-Text-to-Music/blob/main/Mubert_Text_to_Music.ipynb)

Comment: А вы все ячейки выполняли?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на  Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, не фото, а **текст** программы, чтобы возможно было копировать через буфер для тех, которые вам хотят помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из того куска кода который вы показываете, вы передаете в get_track_by_tags переменную pat, но он ее не может найти так как  она не объявлена не в самой функции generate_track_by_promt, не в основном коде данного файла. Он ее просто не может найти. Возможно она у вас в другом файле?

Comment: Там в одной из ячеек ноутбука задаётся эта переменная, но, видимо, автор вопроса эту ячейку не выполнял